# Asp.net- Report viewer export to Image in a local processing mode

Tags: asp.net, report, viewer

The following code i am using to export as a image in local processing mode is

```
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = mimeType;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename= hi." + "jpeg");
Response.BinaryWrite(byts);
Response.Flush();
Warning[] warnings;
string[] streamids;
string encoding;
string extension;
string mimeType = "image/png";'
string deviceInfo ="<DeviceInfo><OutputFormat>PNG</OutputFormat></DeviceInfo>";
byte[] byts = null;
byts = ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Render("Image", deviceInfo , out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamids, out warnings);
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = mimeType;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename= hi." + "jpeg");
Response.BinaryWrite(byts);
Response.Flush();
```

here code is working fine, but it does not export the complete report as a image, only the first page is exporting as image, i could not see the second page as a image,
Please help me out
Thanks in advance

Shanmugapriya.D

Answer (score 2):

You can only get image for one page from ReportViewer control. What you can do is to generate images for all pages - either by changing `CurrentPage` property of the control or using the [Render overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251837.aspx) that takes CreateStreamCallback such as

```
private Stream LocalReportCreateStreamCallback(string name, string extension,
      Encoding encoding, string mimeType,bool willSeek)
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    m_pages.Add(stream);
    return stream;
}
```

In such case, Render method keeps calling on the call-back till on pages are finished and thus you will have your `m_pages` collection filled with data for all page images. Now, you can probably zip all those images and send across the response or you may use some image manipulation library to stitch those images together to form one big image to return back (not a good idea because it will put quite a load on your server).

Typically, if you are going to create pre-view sort of thing then good idea would be to cache those images and return the html that would contain hyperlinks to those images.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the StartPage element to your device info and set it to "0". See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155373.aspx.